# Finding deployment date of a smart contract using its address

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, solana-web3js

Is there any possible way to find the deployment date of a smart contract created on the Solana chain.
For eg, finding the deployment or creation date for the following contract address:

DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263 (Bonk token contract address)

Is there an available public api or python or js library to get token deployment date?Or by looking at the earliest transactions or transfers?

I tried searching for Solana Blockchain explorers but couldn't find a date on any of the explorers. Out of all my attempts only solscan had an api but not much info was provided on the public api.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go back through every block to find the first one that includes the mint address, and that one will likely contain the mint creation transaction.

If you do a binary search through all Solana blocks, I hope this won't take too long!